# How to add codeblocks executable in gitignore?

Tags: codeblocks, gitignore

I am using codeblocks IDE for opencv programming in c, so when i build and run the program it generate executable which opens through AptURl
,how to add that executable in .gitignore ?

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` can help exclude files based on their:

- **naming convention** (if you know the extension of the executable, or -- if it has no extension -- its likely name, you can add it or a pattern matching its name to the `.gitignore`)
- **location**: even when the name is unknown in advance, the project could decide to generate it in a dedicated subfolder that can then be added to the `.gitignore`.